# Do I need to escape a separator character in a file path in java

Tags: java, path-separator

There are many questions on escape characters but I seem unable to find an answer when using File.separator

I am using a system dependant separator character which I am creating with this code:

```
public class SeparatorCharactor
{
    public static String createSeparatorCharactor()
    {
        String sep = File.separator;
        return sep;
        //I could use *return File.separator;* but I prefer to do it in 2 steps.
    }
}
```

My understanding is that this creates a file separator that will work on any operating system.

I am then using the file separator like this :

```
private String sep = SeparatorCharactor.createSeparatorCharactor();
private String path = "S:"
   + sep + "folder1"
   + sep + "folder2";
```

My Question is : Do I need to escape the file separator ?

In other words do I need :

1. `"S" + sep + "folder1"`

or

2. `"S" + sep + sep + "folder1"`

Comment: You do not. You also can use `/` on every platform, the JVM will translate it to ``\`` on Windows (which is the only platform that uses ``\`` anyway).

Comment: Don't do it at all. Use `Path p = Path.of("x", "y", "z", "foo.pdf");`

Comment: Escaping is something that only has to be done with String literals in your code. (Those things between `"`).

Comment: Regarding your comment in the first method: *why* do you prefer to write overly verbose code? That’s a bad habit that you should work on breaking ASAP.

Comment: Off topic but that SeparatorCharactor class doesn't add any value and adds noise to your code.

Comment: @aled I was going to ask WHY but now I've thought about it, is it because File.separator is static ?

Comment: There is no point in struggling with combining things. Use the built-in `Paths` class for path operations. Example: `Path path = Paths.get("dir1", "dir2", "file.txt");` in `java.nio.file` package.

Comment: @MustafaÖzçetin I already mentioned that

Comment: @g00se: Right, but mine is yet another alternative for older Java (7+) versions. `Path.of()` is newer.

Comment: @g00se Thank you. I didn't know about the Path class. This makes life a lot easier. For anyone reading this in the future, the documentation is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathClass.html)

Comment: Ah right - missed that sorry

Comment: @3rdRockSoftware think about what behavior or benefit does that class add to your code. Does it justify to be added? it just exists to return the same value that File.separator has. It is just code bloat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to escape the file separator ?

No, you do *not* need to escape the separator in a path in Java.

Just use the forward-slash character (`/`) to indicate a file path separator in a generic sense.

The file-related libraries in Java automatically translate the forward-slash character to the platform-specific character.

The `/` translates to:

- `/` on Unix-oriented platforms such as macOS, Linux, AIX, and BSD.
- `\` on Microsoft Windows.
- `:` on [legacy Mac OS 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_Mac_OS) and earlier.

---

> do I need : `"S" + sep + "folder1"` or `"S" + sep + sep + "folder1"`

Neither.

In modern Java, use the convenient classes provided by [NIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html). See [`Path.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#of(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...)) or [`Paths.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...)).

```
Path path = Path.of( "S", "folder1" , "folder2" );
```

---

> separator character which I am creating with this code

No, do not create a method for that purpose. Your method adds no value. Calling that method will only confuse anyone reading your code.

If you want to use a constant provided by the JVM, just use it. Just call `File.separator` directly.

---

Tip: Be careful in selecting a tutorial or article about file-handling in Java.

The early versions of Java had file-related classes that were awkward and confusing. Many pages were written in trying  to explain these. Avoid such outdated material.

Those legacy file-handling classes were supplanted by the modern classes of [NIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) and NIO.2. Focus on these classes when studying Java.

Comment: The Wikipedia link is about non-blocking IO. That's too advanced a subject. NIO stands for "New IO", so there's no need to talk about non-blocking.

Comment: @k314159 Very well, I changed the links to the Oracle Java Tutorials. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Java does not translate anything, or at least, most Windows file system APIs support both `/` and ``\`` as the path separator.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not. You don't need to escape it. But also in your code `"S" + sep + sep + "folder1"` you rely that the value of your `sep` variable is "`\`" which is not guaranteed. So if you wanted to escape it you would have to do `"S" + "\\" + sep + "folder1"`. But again not only you don't need to do it, but if you do you will get unexpected and incorrect result

Comment: I now understand I don't need it at all but, why is the value of **sep** not guaranteed if the code that generates it, creates the correct separator for the platform the code is running on ?

Comment: Because if you run the same code on Linux the value will be "/" and only on Windows it is "\". But for escaping you always need "\"

Comment: @user16320675 yes you are correct, I edited my answer. It of course has to be "\\" instead of "\"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for all your answers.

I have now adapted my code to use the Path API like this:

```
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Path;

private Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(
            "Root",
            "folder1",
            "folder2",
            "filename.zzz"
    );
```

This works perfectly.

The complete path can be accessed by using
`path.toString() //"C:\Root\folder1\folder2\filename.zzz"`

The parent folder =
`path.getParent() //"C:\Root\folder1\folder2"`

The filename =
`path.getFilename() //"filename.zzz"`

Comment: I'm not certain, but I suspect *FileSystems.getDefault().getPath()* isn't buying you anything over `Path.of`

Comment: for some reason I couldn't get `Path.of`` to work. The IDE (netbeans) wouldn't accept ".of" as a valid method

Comment: Your jdk must be old. That came in with Java 11. You should probably update

Comment: oh if only... I work for a state run medical agency who still insist on using windows 8 on some client machines :-)

Comment: In older Java versions, you need to use [`Paths.get(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...)) (supported since Java 7) instead of [`Path.of(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#of(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...)) (since Java 11)